# Workaround for floats in DOMPDF

Tags: php, css, pdf, pdf-generation, dompdf

DOMPDF [does not support floats](http://www.digitaljunkies.ca/dompdf/css21.php).

However I am listing many tables, and they are mainly key & value pairs. I would like 2 of these tables to appear side by side.

i.e. if I *could* use floats

### HTML

```
<table id="stuff">
...
</table>

<table id="other-stuff">
...
</table>
```

### CSS

```
table#stuff {
    float: left;
}

table#other-stuff {
    float: right;
}
```

What sort of workaround can I do to support this? Or is it impossible?

If anyone has any ideas, there is a place to test [here](http://www.digitaljunkies.ca/dompdf/examples.php#demo).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like it *may* be [supported in the beta](http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/issues/detail?id=137#c1).

You can [download](http://dompdf.googlecode.com/files/dompdf_0-6-0_beta1.zip) that from the [Google Code page](http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/).

Answer (score 3):

Make a table with 2 cells (50% if needed). Align 1st to left and the 2nd to right.
In each cell you place your tables.

It should look like 2 floats.